# Triple integral $\iiint x{e^{ax+by+cz}} dV$over unit sphere ${x^2}+{y^2}+{z^2}\le1$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Integrate,

$$\iiint x{e^{ax+by+cz}} dV$$

where a, b, c are constants and  over the region ${x^2}+{y^2}+{z^2}\le1$

I am struggling with triple integrals because I'm never sure which change of variable will help me with a certain problem. I've tried cartesian, spherical polar and cylindrical polar but didn't get anywhere... it is possible I made mistakes though. Thank you for your help!

Edit: New idea, make a new orthonormal basis, with one vector pointing in the direction of a, so we have
e1=(a,b,c)
e2=(0,-c,b)
e3=e1xe2=(${b^2}+{c^2},-ab,-ac$)

Comment: please show us what you tried exactly. What did you get with those different coordinates?

Comment: For cartesian coordinates the limits I used were 1 and -1 for dz. $sqrt(1-{x^2})$ and $-sqrt(1-{x^2})$ for dy and $sqrt(1-{x^2}-{y^2})$ and $-sqrt(1-{x^2}-{y^2})$ for dx. (forgive my lack of Mathjax knowledge). This got too complicated after the first integral because there are several y's in the exponential.

Comment: For cylindrical polar converting the thing we are integrating to the right form proved too difficult because $ax+by+cz$ isn't easily expressed, similarly for spherical polar. Both times the integral becomes too complicated for me

Comment: When adding relevant content, please click on the tiny `edit` to improve the **body of the post** instead of commenting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the variables $(x,y,z)\rightarrow (u,v,w)$ according to

$$u = x\cos\alpha -y\sin\alpha $$
$$v = x\cos\beta \sin\alpha + y\cos\beta\cos\alpha -z\sin\beta$$
$$w = x\sin\beta \sin\alpha  + y\sin\beta\cos\alpha  + z\cos\beta $$

which corresponds to the rotations of angle $\alpha$ around the $z$-axis, followed by angle $\beta$ around the $x$-axis. The sine and cosine coefficients are determined by $a$, $b$ and $c$ as follows,
$$\cos\alpha = \frac b{p},\>\>\>
\sin\alpha = \frac a{p},\>\>\>
\cos\beta = \frac c{q},\>\>\>
\sin\beta = \frac {p}{q}$$
with $p=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ and $q=\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}$. The transformation aligns the direction $(a,b,c)$ along the $w$-axis. As a result, the components in the integrand can be written as,
$$ax+by+cz = qw,\>\>\>\>\>\>\>x = \frac bp u + \frac{ac}{pq} v + \frac aq w  $$

and the integral simplifies to

$$I=\int_{V} x{e^{ax+by+cz}} dxdydz
=\frac aq\int_{V}  w \>{e^{qw}} dudvdw$$

where it is recognized that the integrations with respect to the $u$ and $v$ terms vanish due to symmetry. Then, integrate in spherical coordinates to obtain,

\begin{align}
I&=\frac{2\pi a}q \int_0^{\pi} \int_0^1  {e^{qr\cos\theta}} r^3\cos\theta\sin\theta drd\theta\\
&=\frac{4\pi a}q\int_0^1 
\left(\frac1{qr}\cosh qr-\frac1{q^2r^2}\sinh qr\right)r^3 dr\\
&=\frac{4\pi a}{q^5}
[(q^2+3)\sinh q - 3q \cosh q]
\end{align}